# Исправить Регулярное выражение, для исправления url изображения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно обрабатывать текст в котором присутствуют изображения 
url изображения могут быть разной вложенности и с разными директоиями
но все такого плана:

```
<img src ="https://domain.ru/img/izdelia/kategory/name/product_name.JPG" 
alt="ALT" width="550" height="377" />
```

нужно получить в \\3 product_name.JPG

первая \\1 зарезервирована под классы (если картинка с классами css)

```
$content = preg_replace('!<img(.*?)src(.*?)(\/.*?\.JPG|jpg|GIF|gif|PNG|png)" 
alt="(.*?)" width(.*?)height(.*?)\s\/>!si',
1-\\1
2-\\2
3-\\3
4-\\4
5-\\5
6-\\6
,$content);
```

что то я сделал не так, выводит

```
1- 
2-="https:
3-//domain.ru/img/izdelia/kategory/name/product_name.JPG
4-ALT
5-="550" 
6-="377"
```

а нужно

```
1- 
2-https://domain.ru/img/izdelia/kategory/name/
3-product_name.JPG
4-ALT
5-550 
6-377
```

Помогите пожалуйста устранить ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
$content = preg_replace('!<img(.*?)src="(.*?)([^/]*)" alt="(.*?)" width="
(.*?)" height="(.*?)"\s\/>!si',
```